# How do I subscribe a global variable to a BehaviorSubject?

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm building a login function and I want certain buttons in the app.component template to appear the moment the user has logged in. I am trying to use BehaviorSubject for this. I'm using an `*ngIf` for the buttons in the template and the condition is a variable called `loggedIn`. However when I try to initialize the loggedIn variable with the result of the SubjectBehavior subscription i get the error:

```
ERROR in app.component.ts(10,3): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

I don't know whats causing this because I am returning a boolean, not an observable. Here is the code of app.component:

```
export class AppComponent {
  private loggedIn: boolean = this.loginService.isLoggedIn().pipe(
    map((isLoggedIn: boolean) => {         // {3}
      if (!isLoggedIn){
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }));

  constructor(private loginService: LoginService){}

  logout():void{
    this.loginService.logout();
  }

}
```

and heres the relevant code of the loginService:

```
   isLoggedIn():BehaviorSubject<boolean>{
    return this.loggedIn; 
  }

  login(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.post(this.authUrl, JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password}), {headers: this.headers}).map((response: Response) => {
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            let token: any = response.json().token;
            if (token) {
                // store username and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ username: username, token: token }));
                this.loggedIn.next(true);
                // return true to indicate successful login
                return true;
            } else {
                // return false to indicate failed login
                return false;
            }
        }).catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a Behavior Subject, you don't have to call the function agian, you can directly use the Subject as follows,

```
 login() {
    this.loginService.login(this.user.name,this.user.password).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.loginService.loggedIn.next(true);
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      }, (error) => {
        this.loginService.loggedIn.next(false);
        if (error.status == 400) {
          this.showErrorAlert();
        } else {
          console.log(error);
        }
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is that i should use the subscribe method instead of pipe like so:

```
  constructor(private loginService: LoginService){
    this.loginService.isLoggedIn().subscribe((isLoggedIn: boolean) =>
    {
      if (!isLoggedIn){
        this.loggedIn = false;
      }
      this.loggedIn = true;
    })
```